# doesNotThrow in Node.js returns undefined

Tags: node.js, nodeunit

In my NodeUnit tests, I have such a piece of code:

```
exports['aTest'] = function(test){
...
var functionResult = test.doesNotThrow(aFunction(aParam));
...
}
```

But functionResult is undefined after the call to doesNotThrow(...)
Why does test.doesNotThrow() not return the result of the function call?
That would be quite elegant.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return anything as shown in the [source code](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/blob/master/lib/assert.js#L311-L340), this is because nodeunit relies on `AssertionError` to determine if a suite succeeded or not, as you could see [here](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/blob/master/lib/assert.js#L112-L120)

Why would you want it to return something, what return value would you expect?
The purpose of the library is to test your assertions. It should not return a value since that would mean giving you info to do something with that value, instead, when an assertion throws you will get a console message saying that your tests got broken. I believe this is a good approach.

Your goal is to be notified when something brokes, relying on the library to tell you what broke, not to delve yourself into the details, that is why I believe the author chose this way.

Comment: Returning undefined is strictly inferior to returning the result of the call doesNotThrow(...) has made.

Comment: That is because this is unit testing, you are testing that the function does not throw, in another test you will test for a result and see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: I am wondering why chaining assertions is considered a bad practice. cf this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430429/are-multiple-asserts-bad-in-a-unit-test-even-if-chaining

Comment: Because you are testing multiple things at once, it's called unit testing because you test single units of logic, each on its own.

Comment: Test one feature per test, don't try to test a lot of them together. I advice you to open a new question if this didn't answer. Or if it did please upvote/mark as accepted.